# How can you parameterize ColorMapEntry in a style?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is is possible to parametrize ColorMapEntry in a style. I want to be able to specify different values for "quantity" in ColorMapEntry when I request a raster layer?

Comment: I assume you have seen the the [many color gradient](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/rasters.html#many-color-gradient) section of geoserver's SLD cookbook. Are you asking about supplying a parameter in place of the quantity? Something like: quantity=<parameter>value</parameter>

Comment: That's right. I want to be able to have a parameter or an expression with this parameter instead of a hardcoded value so that I can set it in my wms request.

Comment: For example: 
<sld:ColorMap>
<sld:ColorMapEntry color="#ff00ff" opacity="1.0" quantity="-1.11111E7" label="no design"/>
...

</sld:ColorMap> I want to be able to set quantity dynamically when I request a layer by passing in a parameter on a wms request.